# How to build a type-safe multiple property groupBy in typescript

Tags: typescript, group-by, type-safety

I already had a groupBy function which receives an array of objects and a key. It is capable to group by a single property.

```
const groupBy = <T extends Record<string, unknown>, U extends keyof T>(
  objArr: T[],
  key: U,
): { [key: string]: T[] }
```

Since I get a `depth=1` object as a result, I was pretty satisfied with the return type being `{ [key: string]: T[] }`

But now I need to extend this function to be able to group by multiple properties and create a nested object with `depth=keys.length`.

the `groupBy` function:

```
const groupBy = <T extends Record<string, unknown>, U extends keyof T>(
  objArr: T[],
  key: U,
): { [key: string]: T[] } => objArr
    .reduce((memo, x) => {
      if (x[key]) {
        const value = (x[key] as any).toString();
        if (!memo[value]) {
          memo[value] = [];
        }
        memo[value].push(x);
      }
      return memo;
    }, {} as { [key: string]: Array<T> });
```

The `groupByMulti` function, that just calls the `groupBy` function recursively until it reaches the last grouping key.

```
const groupByMulti = <T extends Record<string, unknown>, U extends keyof T>(
  arr: T[],
  keys: U[],
  propIndex = 0,
) => {
  const grouppedObj = groupBy(arr, keys[propIndex]);
  Object.keys(grouppedObj).forEach((key) => {
    if (propIndex < keys.length - 1) {
      grouppedObj[key] = groupByMulti(grouppedObj[key], keys, propIndex + 1);
    }
  });
  return grouppedObj;
}
```

I was wondering if it is possible to build an object type with a fixed depth like:

```
  groupByMulti(someArray, ['key1', 'key2']): {
    [key: string]: {
      [key: string]: T[]
    }
  }

// Depending on the keys length, for example

    groupByMulti(someArray, ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']): {
      [key: string]: {
        [key: string]: {
          [key: string]: T[]
        }
      }
    }
```

I know that this might be possible only if the keys are a ReadonlyArray, but I could live with that.
If not possible, How can I achieve any amount of type-safety here?

Example converted to `JS`, to exemplify:

```js
const cars = [{
    car: 'Audi',
    model: 'A6',
    style: 'Sedan',
    year: '2005',
  },
  {

    car: 'Audi',
    model: 'A4',
    style: 'Sedan',
    year: '2018',
  },
  {

    car: 'Toyota',
    model: 'Corola',
    style: 'Sedan',
    year: '2006',
  },
  {

    car: 'Toyota',
    model: 'Camry',
    style: 'Sedan',
    year: '2006',
  },
]


const groupBy = (
    objArr,
    property,
  ) => objArr
  .reduce((memo, x) => {
    if (x[property]) {
      const value = (x[property]).toString();
      if (!memo[value]) {
        memo[value] = [];
      }
      memo[value].push(x);
    }
    return memo;
  }, {});

const groupByMulti = (arr, keys, propIndex = 0) => {
  var grouppedObj = groupBy(arr, keys[propIndex]);
  Object.keys(grouppedObj).forEach((key) => {
    if (propIndex < keys.length - 1) {
      grouppedObj[key] = groupByMulti(grouppedObj[key], keys, propIndex + 1);
    }
  });
  return grouppedObj;
}


console.log(JSON.stringify(groupByMulti(cars, ['car', 'year', 'model']), null, 2));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume you care more about type safety from the *caller's* side, especially since your existing `groupBy()` function has at least one `as any` [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) inside its implementation.

Let's say that the call signature of `groupByMulti()` should look like:

```
<T extends Record<K[number], {}>, K extends readonly (keyof T)[]>(
  arr: readonly T[], 
  keys: readonly [...K],
  propIndex?: number
) => GroupByMulti<T, K>
```

for some appropriate definition of `GroupByMulti`.

Before we get to `GroupByMulti`, let me explain the rest of that call signature:

We want `K` to be a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) of keys, and we want `T` to be an object type with properties at `K` whose values at those properties are assignable to `{}`, the so-called [empty object type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-oop.html#empty-types) which (despite the name) accepts all primitives (like `string` or `number`) and only rejects `null` and `undefined`. I did this because you call `.toString()` on those properties, and we don't want possibly-`undefined` or `null` properties to be in there.

If you're wondering about `readonly XXX[]`, it's because [`readonly` arrays](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#the-readonlyarray-type) and [`readonly` tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-tuple-types) are *less* restrictive than "normal" arrays.  (The names are deceptive; `readonly` here means "can definitely be read, but may or may not be written", while regular arrays are "can definitely be read, and can definitely be written").

And finally the fact that `keys` is `[...K]` instead of just `K` is using [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) to give the compiler a hint that we want it to keep track of the exact length of that array, since it makes a big difference.

---

Okay, now let's define `GroupByMulti`:

```
type GroupByMulti<T, K extends readonly any[]> =
    K extends readonly [any, ...infer KR] ?
    Record<string, GroupByMulti<T, KR>> : readonly T[];
```

That's a [recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) that walks through the `K` tuple.  If `K` is empty, we just want `readonly T[]`, that is, grouping by no keys just gives you an array.  Otherwise, we want `Record<string, GroupByMulti<T, KR>>` where `KR` is an array that's shorter by one than `K`.  (It's the `R`est of the `K` array so I call it `KR`. ‍♂️).

The implementation is full of type assertions I won't spend time explaining:

```
const groupByMulti = <
    T extends Record<K[number], {}>,
    K extends readonly (keyof T)[]
>(arr: readonly T[], keys: readonly [...K], propIndex = 0) => {
    var grouppedObj: any = groupBy(arr, keys[propIndex]);
    Object.keys(grouppedObj).forEach((key) => {
        if (propIndex < keys.length - 1) {
            grouppedObj[key] = groupByMulti<any, any[]>(
                grouppedObj[key], keys, propIndex + 1);
        } else {
            grouppedObj[key] = grouppedObj[key]
        }
    });
    return grouppedObj as GroupByMulti<T, K>;
}
```

The only important bit is that we are returning a value of type `GroupByMulti<T, K>`.  Let's test it out:

---

```
const result = groupByMulti(cars, ['car', 'year', 'model']);
/* const result: Record<string, Record<string, Record<string, readonly {
    car: string;
    model: string;
    style: string;
    year: string;
}[]>>> */

Object.keys(result).forEach(k =>
    Object.keys(result[k]).forEach(l =>
        Object.keys(result[k][l]).forEach(m => {
            result[k][l][m].forEach(c => console.log(c.car));
        })
    )
)
```

Looks good.  The type of `result` is a triply-nested object with `string` keys, whose deep object type is the an of `T` objects.  That allows us to process the result with some type safety (the compiler knows that `result[k][l][m]` is an array).

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBMCGAnCMC8MDaBvAsAKBkLiQC4YByAQQFcATAS3IBp8iYBbEWgUwBsyqANmasi0AJ69uAgMrda8MCIJFx3UhQBMABm0BWZQF8WeXHlGEEiATQbK2nHvwqUALPbFRJ0inIVKTNjUNch0ARgAOIxMzC2JrCgAVEHEQKHgPQkc+AQBhEEQQXgzAz29ZeUVMmGCE0N1hE2N8WJVLEOTU9Ors53Jc+HZEcWqJKQr-atqBHW1G-Ga8AF18VbxQSFgAc0LqAAcAIXE0GAAeRJhuAA8objBaFAAlblBEWlOAaSYYLEMAPm+H0uNzuDxgAGtuKkAGYwRJ-AAUcRAACMAFaURAJRDqWjgXjHRIYJalQh7Qp7biILxkL74ACUaD+MFRGKxADocbRqMBuAiEexuJxvldGahmWY2PRYQirhhySBKdTxEtGZK2EQNtAYAA3eC8ajcE6y+UUqleVXsqAgGRQRD0MBbBH0gDccSlMoAhILOBg9QbuKqfu6NVkhSA-frDUsTsS3W0NYYQ2Hff7o+y9tQIAALWWuuJJhM4qDURBgDjh+PGH6GGDwJ4vArvaD2x3fIlLP758w9ryUmAAcV2h3EAFlqLwoPRzoDgbd7igcfA8WACXWwOJiczUHEgdd52Clyu1xhFOJvuzLw7oVSYB9HjGAPxxZ6vZt2h1bb5DkD7I7jydp0SQFHj+ZkyCPfFCTjNYtW2Yd-wnKcTlOOILn3UEGzfT4MDAah2BRKkSRrAFdznTCYEg1djgRSEYTheliXwREkGxXEoLhYlvjoiAIPY6jMEvdkPmIhU9gASXua4Tm0MUJTiPVEBgHZfz2SlaAAeXRMgzxOFS-3EBFWO4qEIFNRVJJ4K5VXjNgtLRF4oHZHiEX0tT5Hs+l2WhAoAFF4GAXNaKhOTgwTD0YARMTLOk04IVM9kpEdKBsxgABaGAwjVZMNTc9T7IwOiY3QNzEMA04z2+M8tyRcLQ1y4d8vRQqoWInjvmiqSrhgABqTLu3qmBaz4CAjXVQbCDyjzmqKvTGumtEWpVHLCzYQwBqIYtS3LKbNPROsUB-AyAKnGc7z+Ks1nwODKO4CAkLm1SyqnBErAgb4MHIKxmAoWofvIXpyBs-AAHoACo4HAbUcXuycyFfJtThbT9vgRt4kY-NsYDR99Wy-W7lw48b4jIZHHVsohelJzGtgpwgxh8MnabiaYYCZqstzAmAwZBtZ7Mc5zTIRGGkK8nzEH8wLaKZOJ+eAJyXJFydCstcXJdzXgZbqwg5YVoWlagFWMF4VW-IC3N2CZMKJs2u6kKNk2MHYJZvLNqXgCtrUim4RKQCdYB2SsekNtDda4npBlrqh73fadAApGQNIAOXZJnpUMg36W+PDeF4b5NG7NYgA)

Comment: Brilliant! As always @jcalz.